# What are the Mutiny equivalents to Publisher and Flowable in RxJava2

Tags: rx-java2, smallrye

I want to create a buffering Multi to which I can push objects. The Multi is used as a result for a REST endpoint.

What I have so far is:

```java
    class MyService {
        private PublishProcessor<String> deviceStatusProcessor = PublishProcessor.create();
        private Flowable<String> deviceStatusQueue = Flowable.fromPublisher(deviceStatusProcessor);

        public void pushDeviceStatus(DeviceStatus deviceStatus) {
            deviceStatusProcessor.onNext(deviceStatus);
        }

        public Multi<String> getStream() {
            return Multi.createFrom().publisher(deviceStatusQueue);
        }
    }
```

However this code mixes RxJava and Mutiny. What are the Mutiny equivalents for Publisher and Flowable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [BoadcastProcessor](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/#_how_do_i_create_hot_streams) is equivalent to PublishProcessor. There is also [UnicastProcessor](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/#_how_can_i_use_a_unicast_processor), which has buffering, but pushes to only one subscriber.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do.

By default, a Multi won't emit anything until there is a subscription, which in your case I believe would be the REST endpoint (1 subscription per received request).

The UnicastProcessor is storing all the emitted items, in an unbounded manner. So be aware that it may lead to `OutOfMemoryException` if not used carefully if there are items but no one consuming.

The BroadcastProcessor is not storing items, but dispatch them to multiple subscribers.